# A common footer for an entire application [Android]

Tags: android, footer

OK, I wanna know if this can be done..

All I need is a common footer like bar, which will contain ads that are going to be displayed. I was wondering if there was any way by which I can have this part of my application as a common one.

I am aware of the include tag, but all that does is to add a that particular layout anywhere it is referenced. What that does is it prompts a reload of the ad, everytime I move from one activity to another. This is very annoying as there is a new ad request that is being sent everytime I move to a new activity.

I am using admob to display ads.
Hope I have made the question clear.

Comment: I guess you mean the *include* tag

Comment: Yea yea, i had actually typed " < include > " there. That didn't show up there!

Comment: you can edit, highlight it and press the `{}` button. it will add two inverted quotes (`) (is that their name?) so it gets code formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Create your view programatically then store it in a [singleton object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which can be accessed throughout the application, this will avoid having to create a new View each time.

Singleton class example:

```
  public class MySingleFooter
{
    MySingleFooter mySingleFooter;
    View myFooter;

    private MySingleFooter()
{

}

    public static MySingleFooter getInstance()
    {
    if (mySingleFooter == null)
        {
        mySingleFooter = new MySingleFooter();
        }

    return mySingleFooter;
    }

    void setFooter(View myFooter)
    {
        this.myFooter = myFooter;
    }

    View getFooter()
    {
        return myFooter;
    }

}
```

You can set the footer from all activities like this:

```
MySingleFooter footerStore = MySingleFooter.getInstance();
footerStore.setFooter(thefooter);
```

You can retrieve the footer from all activities like this:

```
MySingleFooter footerStore = MySingleFooter.getInstance();
View myview = footerStore.getFooter(thefooter);
```

Then add it to the current activity programatically.

Comment: Wow. Wonder why I didn't think of a solution like this before. Thanks a lot, will test it out and mark your solution as the correct answer after I 'm done..

Comment: I wasn't able to progress on your idea. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441716/admob-android)