# How to maintain custom tab on screen and change class without redrawing the tab again?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-tabs

Let me try to make my question much clearer here. Supposed I have a custom tab created by using buttons and images in XML layout and it looks like this.

[image: Custom Tab]
Each of these buttons, should call a class. Normally, Intent is used to call new class when onClick. But the whole layout would be redrawn when I call any of the classes via Intent.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(TabBar.this, Favourites.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

I tried using TabHost and it worked, but my project requires me to use a custom tab bar.
I also tried the solution to this [Dynamically change view inside view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427278/dynamically-change-view-inside-view-in-android), which is similar to what I wanted, (switching layouts and maintaining the tab bar below it), which worked as well.

My goal is to maintain the custom tab that I have, and change the classes instead of layout without redrawing the custom tab bar everytime I click on every buttons. With classes, I can run different functions and call different activities.

I googled a lot on this but couldn't seem to find a solution or reference. Can somebody guide me? Thanks in advance.

Update :

I'm new in Android, and after attempting many times, I decided to try out codes from AdilSoomro to achieve what I wanted, http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html which is to create custom tabs that looks like iPhone tabs. However, this project uses TabActivity that is now deprecated in Android 4.1. I attempted to change it to FragmentActivity after referring to other sources that uses Fragments for tabs.

- http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/
- http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

I managed to create it using FragmentActivity and here is where you can refer to them :
[How to use custom iPhone tab in FragmentActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193189/solved-how-to-use-custom-iphone-tab-in-fragmentactivity)

Comment: Hiii Change the view with replace view method..

Comment: hey @hardikjoshi :) I'm sorry, I don't really get what you mean. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TabHost` control to achieve this. Go through this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android)
It explains all the possibilities. It also includes using custom tab bar defined in the xml file.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. The post is really useful if I use TabHost, which I tried before. And I could change images and such with the example you gave me.  

Right now, my codes does not use TabHost & TabWidget, the tabs are created entirely using Buttons and Images. And my project requires me to change the tab bar entirely.

Comment: Hey @Pargat I had no choice but get back to TabHost and TabWidget and I get what I wanted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve this is create footer and use it in all your activity. Like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408336/a-common-footer-for-an-entire-application-android). And Let me know its useful as per your requirement or not.

Comment: Hey I am trying out the codes from the link that you posted. What should I be putting in the "thefooter" part?

Comment: I put it like this, under onCreate, is it right? http://pastie.org/pastes/5141169/text?key=kmsdn7yrhr8omubuu7a , the footer don't seem to appear though.

Comment: You need to add footerStore into your current activity view.

Comment: @HoneyH refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7421863/1405983 its give you perfect idea dear.